# Can I build iOS apps in Xcode 4.2 and iOS5, then test the app on iPhone with iOS 4.3

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, ios4

Can I build iOS apps in Xcode 4.2 and iOS5, then test the app on an iPhone running iOS 4.3?

I want to use the storyboard feature in iOS5 and Xcode 4.2, but I don't have a device. I can only borrow a device that runs iOS 4.3.

Comment: as rob mayoff has stated you can't use Storyboard on devices earlier then iOS5

Comment: I'd plug the phone into iTunes and update.

Answer (score 3):

Storyboards are not supported in iOS 4.3.

You can test in the iOS 4.3 simulator (or on an iOS 4.3 device) if you have set your deployment target to 4.3 or lower.  Xcode 4.2 doesn't come with the iOS 4.3 simulator by default.  To install it, open Xcode's Preferences and click the Downloads tab, and the Components tab under that.  From there you can download and install the iOS 4.3 simulator.

You can also send your app to a friend for testing.  Apple documents the steps in the [*Tools Workflow Guide for iOS*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/ios_development_workflow/35-Distributing_Applications/distributing_applications.html).  You can also use http://testflightapp.com/ to let your friend install the app over the network.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will be able to build in Xcode 4.2 directly for iOS 5. However, you will need to set the target version to iOS 4.3. You will also need to be a paid member of the developer program in order to run your applications on a device. See the Apple Developer Portal documentation on mobile provisioning for more info.

Answer (score 0):

**Storyboards are not compatible with iOS 4.** ARC is compatible, and weak references are also sort of compatible.

**Bottom line:** For you, your app is not backwards compatible because you use storyboards. If you'd like, test your app in a iOS 4.3 simulator, or have someone else test it running iOS 5.